# com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/windowstableheaderui error when importing data dictionary in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to import the ERD of my schema in SQL Developer. I get this error when I select my schema and hit next.

[image]

Comment: version of SQL Developer and Java? you can see both on the Help > About dialog

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing the problem, as of November 2020, SQL developer supports only Java 8. You have to download and install jdk8 and update the Java Home in SQL Developer settings.

Comment: 8 or 11..been that way for awhile actually